# How to stop mapping on true results for large lists?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, function-construction, map

Assuming I have a long list (real data with more than 100k elements). I have a function that I want to apply to the list, for example, EvenQ. I want the mapping to stop once the result for one element returns True and the code should return True to minimize computation. If no True is encountered while mapping all elements, then the code should return False. How can I achieve this? The list and the function EvenQ are used here for illustration purposes.

```
list = {1, 3, 5, 2, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19};
EvenQ/@list
```

Answer (score 7):

The `AllTrue` function will short circuit.

```
AllTrue[list, EvenQ]
```

But I may have misunderstood, because you said you want short-circuiting on `True`, so maybe you want

```
AllTrue[list, Not@*EvenQ]
```

which is baically equivalent to

```
AllTrue[list, OddQ]
```

Anyway, you can craft whatever specific function you need.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`AnyTrue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AnyTrue.html).  `AnyTrue` short-circuits on first `True` result and returns `True` in that case.

With

```
list = {1, 3, 5, 2, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19};
```

then

```
AnyTrue[list, EvenQ]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

```
alist = {1, 3, 5, 2, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19};
blist = {1, 3, 5, 7};

f = FirstPosition[#, _?EvenQ, False] /. {_} :> True &;

f /@ {alist, blist}
```

---

*Result:*

```
{True, False}
```

Answer (score 4):

Unlike the case with `Map`, `Throw` may be used to exit from `Scan`

Maybe

```
list = {1, 3, 5, 2, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19};

Catch[{Scan[If[EvenQ[#], Throw[True]] &, list], Throw[False]}]

Catch[{Scan[If[EvenQ[#], Throw[True]] &, DeleteCases[list, 2]], Throw[False]}]

(* 

  True
  False

 *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {1, 3, 5, 2, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19};

TakeWhile[list, EvenQ] == list
```

False

```
LengthWhile[list, EvenQ] == Length[list]
```

False